# WPF Localization Using LocBaml: Handling Special Symbols

Tags: wpf, localization, globalization

I’m dealing with localization of a WPF application (**Visual Studio 2010** under **Windows 7**). I’ve just accomplished the whole process of localization using ***LocBaml*** tool, as explained in **WPF Globalization and Localization Overview** and in related posts.

The target language is **Italian** (***it-IT*** culture). 
When I run my application in Italian, I have a problem with interpretation of the special symbols of © and ™: they both appear there as a white question sign upon a black diamond-shaped background.

The symbols © and ™ appear identically in both English and Italian **CSV**-files.
I tried also the special letters (such as **È, à** etc.) that are present in Italian but absent in English, and they also are interpreted as the above diamond-shaped question.

In **Region and Language**, I changed the system locale to *Italian[Italy]*, restarted the PC and ran the application again – this helped me in the past to cope with a similar problem in localization of C++ applications under Windows XP, but now it didn’t help, either.
Has somebody any idea what is the catch here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my is response is to late, but try saving the localized .csv file with UTF-8 encoding. This worked for me.

Cheers